# Updating scaffold views after adding new column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I created a table using scaffold. Later added a new column

```
$ rails generate migration add_column_name_to_table_name column_name:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

Now I'm wondering is there any way to auto-update earlier generated by scaffold views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you've got to do it manually.

FWIW, these sorts of changes are made much easier if you're using one of [the form generator gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_form_builders).

Comment: That's a pity. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Y'know there's a better way to thank people on StackOverflow, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)